# Mongoose/MongoDb find documents with reverse reference in an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have 2 schemas:

```
Order
- orderId
- date
- items: OrderItem[] (Array of ObjectIds of OrderItem)
```

```
OrderItem
- name
- price
- discount
```

Now I have the list of order items and I want to associate them with order.
As I'm storing the references in the `Order`.

But I need to list all the `OrderItems` in a separate page from where I can link the items to order via API. So I need to see which items are already linked to an order and which are still pending. Is there any way to get the `OrderId` in the list of `OrderItem` with the use of mongoose?

I've tried to reverser reference as well in the `OrderItem` by including the `orderId` in the `OrderItem` schema. But, it causes an issue when I try to link the order items which are already linked.

Say for example, I've 2 orders:

```
o1:
items: i1, i2

o2:
items: i3, i4, i5

i1:
orderId: o1

i2:
orderId: o1

i3:
orderId: o2

i4:
orderId: o2

i5:
orderId: o2

i6:
orderId: o2
```

So from the list of items, user selects i2, i3 to link to o3. Then the following updates has to be made:

```
o3 -> items: i2, i3
i2 -> orderId: o3
i3 -> orderId: o3
```

But it leaves a situation where `o1` still holds `i2` and `o2` still holds `i3`. Those documents also needs to be updated. These many operations leaves an issue for simple linking leads to an complex ambiguous situation.

If there's a way I can get list of items and `orderId` it belongs to without storing `orderId` in the `OrderItem` and only storing it in the `Order.items` can solve this situation.

Is there any way I can achieve this with mongoose / mongodb ?

Comment: How about querying Order collection directly to list all items using `$unwind` and `$lookup`.

Comment: The mongoose way is to load the order and [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) the items. As a side not moving items from one order to another is complex either way as with your current schema you have to update arrays on 3 orders, which leaves a lot of room for race conditions if you don't use multi-document transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing orderItem without orderId lead you to the problems when retrieve order detail from orderItem. Storing orderItemId in order collection is not useful as you think. Because you can get them from orderItem collection. Query nested data is not easy. Try to bring all of them into a line. Just my opinion.

```
Order
- salerId
- buyerId
- date

OrderItem
- orderId
- name
- price
- discount
```

Comment: I think this is the best idea. I didn't think of making another query where I would just store the orderId in the OrderItem and then retrieve for the order with orderId = o1. It just didn't clicked to me at that time! Thanks for bringing this to my attention..